# WPF: tile image

Tags: wpf, image, background, tile

I need to tile a picture in a WPF Image Control (like on Windows Desktop (Background tile property)). Does somebody know weather this is possible and if so, how?

Best regards,
Alexander

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a sample Rectangle that I borrowed from MSDN.

```
DrawingBrush myBrush = new DrawingBrush();

GeometryDrawing backgroundSquare =
    new GeometryDrawing(
        Brushes.White,
        null,
        new RectangleGeometry(new Rect(0, 0, 100, 100)));

GeometryGroup aGeometryGroup = new GeometryGroup();
aGeometryGroup.Children.Add(new RectangleGeometry(new Rect(0, 0, 50, 50)));
aGeometryGroup.Children.Add(new RectangleGeometry(new Rect(50, 50, 50, 50)));

LinearGradientBrush checkerBrush = new LinearGradientBrush();
checkerBrush.GradientStops.Add(new GradientStop(Colors.Black, 0.0));
checkerBrush.GradientStops.Add(new GradientStop(Colors.Gray, 1.0));

GeometryDrawing checkers = new GeometryDrawing(checkerBrush, null, aGeometryGroup);

DrawingGroup checkersDrawingGroup = new DrawingGroup();
checkersDrawingGroup.Children.Add(backgroundSquare);
checkersDrawingGroup.Children.Add(checkers);

myBrush.Drawing = checkersDrawingGroup;
myBrush.Viewport = new Rect(0, 0, 0.25, 0.25);
myBrush.TileMode = TileMode.Tile;

exampleRectangle.Fill = myBrush;
```

It demonstrates how to Tile a rectangle. Here is the link to MSDN:
[WPF Brush Overview - MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970904.aspx)

Comment: Thank you for your replies. Now I got the following XAML code:

<Rectangle>
  <Rectangle.Fill>
    <ImageBrush Viewport="0, 0, 0.25, 0.25" TileMode="Tile" ImageSource="Background1.png"/>
  </Rectangle.Fill>
</Rectangle>

This tiles the picture; but when I resize the Rectangle the "tiled-pictures" get streched. However, I want them to repeat (like a background image on a HTML webpage).

Comment: Found the solution:
<ImageBrush TileMode="Tile" Viewbox="0, 0, 320, 320" ViewboxUnits="Absolute" Viewport="0, 0, 320, 320" ViewportUnits="Absolute" ImageSource="Background1.png"/>

Comment: Sorry I couldn't reply to your comment, I just woke up :P I'm glad you got it all sorted. :D

Answer (score 1):

If you're drawing your image with a [`DrawingBrush`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.drawingbrush.aspx) you can set the property [`TileMode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.tilebrush.tilemode.aspx) to `TileMode.Tile`. Assuming I've understood your question correctly, it does what you want.